# Is there a way to delete the same values out of two different arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a beginner programmer and have recently discovered the Euler Project's problems. I kind of got hooked on the first problem, as it feels like the right level of difficulty for me.

What I want to do is calculate the sum of the multiples of 3 and 5 out of a number range below 1000.

So, I've figured out how to create two seperate arrays with all the multiples of 3 and 5 each.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    eulerList.push(i);               

    if (i%3 == 0 && i != 0) {
        multiThree.push(i);
    }

    if (i%5 == 0 && i != 0) {
        multiFive.push(i);
    }  

    if (i == 999) {
        var eulerSum = multiThree.concat(multiFive);   
        print("The total sum is " + eulerSum.reduce(getSum));    
    }
```

Now, when I tried to calculate the sum of the multiples, it gave me the wrong result and after a while of thinking I realized that is, because some of the numbers are doubled in the list.

Let's say I have an integer value of 15 in arrayA and arrayB, but I only want it to remain in arrayA, so I can finally calculate the total sum of all multiples. How would I approach that? I've been stuck at this, reading on here and googling for hours, but I couldn't wrap my head around it. 
Help would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `var eulerSum = [...(new Set([...multiThree, ...multiFive]))];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create separate arrays are store them and do like that. Just create a variable `sum` and add the numbers to them. The below snippet gives correct result for project euler.

```js
let sum = 0;
for(let i = 0;i<1000;i++){
  if(i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0) sum += i 
}
console.log(sum)
```

You can do that using [Arithmetic series](https://www.purplemath.com/modules/series4.htm) formula

```js
console.log(333/2*(3 + 999) + 199/2*(5 + 995) - 66/2*(15+990));
```

If you still want to solve it using two different arrays. Then you create a `Set()` which will keep only unique values from the two arrays. And no need to check `0` it doesnot effect the sum

```js
let multiThree = [];
let multiFive = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {              
    if (i%3 == 0) {
        multiThree.push(i);
    }
    if (i%5 == 0) {
        multiFive.push(i);
    }  

    if (i == 999) {
        var eulerSum = [...new Set(multiThree.concat(multiFive))];   
        console.log(eulerSum.reduce((ac,a) => ac+a,0))
           
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the second snippet have to do with it?

Comment: @JaromandaX Just added a way to solve the problem using simple math.

Comment: right, so why is the result a different one? `233168 !== 299168` :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Fixed not I actually added the sum of `15` series instead of subtracting.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer was really helpful (and quite shocking for me how you solved my problem with just 5 lines of code.)!

Comment: @pparmin Accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: @Maheer Ali Trying to work through your code, I am getting stuck on the last line: 
```
console.log(eulerSum.reduce((ac,a) => ac+a,0))
```
I figured out you're using a Rest operator and I figured out how to use the Arrow function, however, I don't understand where the values for the parameters (ac, a) for the reduce function come from?

I have accepted your answer already. Sorry for being a bit slow, I'm new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

We can also go with `Array.reduce` and `Array.some` to check if the number encountered is divisible by either 3 *or* 5 and add the number if true to the accumulator of the `Array.reduce` callback.

```js
const sum = Array.from({length: 1000})
           .reduce((acc, ele, idx) => acc = ([3, 5].some(e => idx % e === 0)) ? acc + idx : acc, 0);
console.log(sum);
```